# Estimating dacay constant with Jags

Tags: r, jags

I try to estimate decays for my data. let me explain. imagine, you observe events X, and each event has an effect y, which decays over time exp(-t/Tau). You observe the time t and the event x and what to predict its effect y. Let me show you my JAGS code.

```
model{
for( j in 1:N ){
  for(i in 1:p){
    td[j,i] <- exp( - t[j,i] / Tau[i] )
  }

  mu[j] <- inprod( X[j,]*td[j,] ,beta[] )
  Y[j] ~ dnorm( mu[j], sigma )
}

   for(j in 1:p){
     bsigma[j] ~dgamma(0.001,0.001);
     beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,bsigma[j]);
     Tau[j] ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001);
   }
   sigma  ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
}
```

I generate test data in R as follows:

```
N = 1000;

sigma = 0.1;
beta  = c(0.75,0.33)
tau   = c(5.7,1.3)

X<-cbind(rnorm(N,1,1),rnorm(N,2,1))
t<-cbind(rnorm(N,1,1),rnorm(N,2,1))
t = abs(t);
Y<- rnorm(N,(X*exp(- t/tau ) )%*%as.matrix(beta),sigma)
```

With my model I can successfully find the values for beta, but I fail to estimate the correct values for Tau.
here the complete code:

```
N = 1000;

sigma = 0.1;
beta  = c(0.75,0.33)
tau   = c(5.7,1.3)

X<-cbind(rnorm(N,1,1),rnorm(N,2,1))
t<-cbind(rnorm(N,1,1),rnorm(N,2,1))
t = abs(t);
Y<- rnorm(N,(X*exp(- t/tau ) )%*%as.matrix(beta),sigma)

####JAGS
##################
library(mcmcplots)
library(runjags)
library(rjags)

hmodel_jags<- function(X,Y,t){
  modelstring = "
  model{
    for( j in 1:N ){
      for(i in 1:p){
        td[j,i] <- exp( - t[j,i] / Tau[i] )
      }

     mu[j] <- inprod( X[j,]*td[j,] ,beta[] )
      Y[j] ~ dnorm( mu[j], sigma )
    }

    for(j in 1:p){
      bsigma[j] ~dgamma(0.001,0.001);
      beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,bsigma[j]);
      Tau[j] ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001);
    }
    sigma  ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
  }"
  writeLines(modelstring,con="dec.txt")
  ########
  set.seed(123)


  jags_data <- list(Y = Y,
                t = t,
                X = X,
                p = ncol(X),
                N=nrow(X)
                )
  params <- c( "Tau",'sigma','beta') 
  adapt <- 1000
  burn <- 1000
  iterations <- 1000
  inits <- list( )

  sample <- run.jags(model="dec.txt", thin =2, monitor=params,data=jags_data, n.chains=2, inits=inits, adapt=adapt, burnin=burn,      sample=iterations, summarise=T, method="parallel") 

  sample
}
res_jags_het <- hmodel_jags(X,Y,t)
```

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand your code.  It would be helpful if you explained, starting from your simulation, what data to treat as observed, and what parameters you want to estimate (it would also help if you avoided using `sigma` as a precision in the JAGS code, and then as a std deviation in the R script).
One immediate puzzlement: in your R script `beta` if fixed.  But in your JAGS code, rather than giving a `beta` an uninformative prior, you assume it comes from a normal distribution with a fixed mean and modeled precision.  Why?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and pointing out my mistake with sigma.
t,y,x are observed. I want to estimate beta and tau.
Normal gamma combination, with prior mean 0 should be similar to ridge regression or when think about it like ARD. bayesian regression, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in your data simulation.  You have

```
 Y<- rnorm(N,(X*exp(- t/tau ) )%*%as.matrix(beta),sigma)
```

Focus on `t/tau`.  Look what happens if you do

```
 t <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), ncol=2)
 tau <- c(1,20)
 t/tau
 [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 1.00  2.0
 [2,] 0.05  0.1
 [3,] 1.00  2.0
 [4,] 0.05  0.1
 [5,] 1.00  2.0
 [6,] 0.05  0.1
```

There are several ways to fix this, the most intuitive of which is to loop over the rows of t.

```
 tt <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=dim(t)[1], ncol=dim(t)[2])
 for(i in 1:dim(t)[1]){
   tt[i,] <- t[i,]/tau
 }
 tt
 [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1  0.1
 [2,]    1  0.1
 [3,]    1  0.1
 [4,]    1  0.1
 [5,]    1  0.1
 [6,]    1  0.1
```

I haven't had time to rerun the JAGS model though to confirm that this is the only problem--I gotta get out the door!

Comment: Yes, that’s it. thank you so much! stupid me, that I haven’t properly debugged it, I was assuming that it does what I thought it does. You really helped me out. thanks man !